# Why Spring injecting different values for Athentication object in the same method?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

If I have the following controller Spring MVC controller method:

```
public MyModel getUserSessionDetails(Authentication authentication1) {
        final Authentication authentication2 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
...
}
```

If the user is not authenticated yet then I get:

```
authentication1 = null
```

`authentication2 =` valid object with principal type of String

If the user is authenticated then both `authentication1` and `authentication2` are identical.

Why we have Spring injecting null if the Authentication is in the method param but have some default authentication object when accessing it through SecurityContextHolder ?

Thanks

Comment: If that `authentication2` is an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` with principal as `anonymousUser` then is normal. What do see when you inspect `authentication2`?

Comment: Yes, it is `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` with `anonymousUser` as the principal for `authentication1`'. Sorry I am not very deep into Spring MVC, but why that is normal? What I don't understand is why in this case `authentication1` is null?

Comment: Quote from the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#anonymous): "Note that there is no real conceptual difference between a user who is "anonymously authenticated" and an unauthenticated user. Spring Security’s anonymous authentication just gives you a more convenient way to configure your access-control attributes. Calls to servlet API calls such as getCallerPrincipal, for example, will still return null even though there is actually an anonymous authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder."